# String functions in C driver development on Win7

Tags: c++, string, kernel, wdk

I'm coming from user-level development and I'm completely new to C/C++ on the kernel level. What I have to implement is a string parser based on a split function like strtok known from string.h. 
As far as I discovered yet one can not use string.h or cstring.h anymore. Then I found out about the WDF and its wdfstring.h but there are just some "constructor"-functions in there, where is the rest?

So my main question is: What functions for string manipulation are available and what do I have to create? I don't want to reinvent the wheel, you know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean C rather than C++ I presume

Comment: Maybe, I'll take whatever I can get ;)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to take a look at the ["Kernel Safe String functions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff565779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There are a number of functions, and they are written to be "safe", which the standard library ones aren't (typically).

Comment: ok, that's what I already discovered, but I still miss some helpful things like strtok

Comment: `strtok` is unsafe even in userspace, and it isn't hard to write a `strtok_r` replacement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The ["run-time library"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has some useful routines for handling strings, but I don't think they have anything akin to strtok. As has been previously suggested, it should be relatively easy to write replacement functions manually.